# Converter string em Date (dd-mm-yyyy)

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma `string = "01/04/2012"` e preciso converter para `date(dd-mm-yyyy)` em *javascript* puro.

Segue o que eu fiz:

```
var vencimento = localStorage.getItem('dados2'); //Busca a variável que contém a string = 01/04/2012
var vencimento2 = new Date(vencimento); // = Wed Jan 04 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão)
var vencimento3 = ???
```

Como eu poderia transformar essa data em `DD-MM-YYYY` ? Só achei exemplos em *jQuery*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pode fazer a seguinte função:

```
function toDate(dateStr) {
    var parts = dateStr.split("/");
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
}
```

Qualquer dúvida ou sugestão adicional segue o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date).

Answer (score 8):

Você pode "explodir" os valores separando-os pela barra.

Por exemplo:

```js
/* Separa os valores */
let dataString = "01/04/2012".split("/");

/* Define a data com os valores separados */
let data = new Date(dataString[2], dataString[1]-1, dataString[0]);

console.log( data.toString() );
console.log( data.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR") );
```

Comment: Cara, mas ai não fica como date. Fiz aqui ele volta a data com string dnv, do mesmo jeito que eu puxo ela

Comment: Quando você atribui `new Date(dataString[2], dataString[1]-1, dataString[0]);`, você já tem o formato `Date`, inclusive podendo adicionar, subtrair, alterar valores.

Answer (score 2):

Sei que faz tempo que essa pergunta foi respondida, mas para conhecimento, temos outra opção.

```
function toDateISO(dateStr) {
    return dateStr.split('/').reverse().join('-');
}

toDateISO('30/12/2021'); // 2021-12-30
```

É possível converter para Date, se assim desejar, basta colocar `new Date()`.

```
function toDate(dateStr) {
    return new Date(dateStr.split('/').reverse().join('-') + ' 00:00:00');
}

toDateISO('30/12/2021'); // Thu Dec 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
```

Sem o horário a resposta será diferente, como pode ser observado abaixo.

```
function toDate(dateStr) {
    return new Date(dateStr.split('/').reverse().join('-'));
}

toDateISO('30/12/2021'); // Thu Dec 29 2021 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
```